# PGFplots - How to set fill opacity for a colorbar?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm having trouble changing the `fill opacity` parameter for a `colorbar` when I use a `surf` graph. It seems that the `fill opacity` parameter of the `colorbar` is always (re)set to 1.

Surprisingly, if I use a `contour filled` graph, the problem does not appear.

What am I doing wrong?

For example, in the graph below, I would like the `fill opacity` of the `colorbar` to be equal to the `fill opacity` of the surface, which is equal to 0.5.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar,
            colorbar style={text opacity=1.0, fill opacity=0.5}]
        \addplot3[fill opacity=0.5,
%       contour filled,
        surf
        ] coordinates {
            (0,0,6) (0,2,9) (0,4,10) (0,6,8)
            
            (2,0,7) (2,2,11) (2,4,11) (2,6,9)
            
            (4,0,8) (4,2,10) (4,4,9) (4,6,8)
            
            (6,0,5) (6,2,9) (6,4,7) (6,6,4)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
colorbar,
colorbar style={fill opacity=0.5, tick label style={opacity=1}},
]
\addplot3[
fill opacity=0.5,
surf,
] coordinates {
            (0,0,6) (0,2,9) (0,4,10) (0,6,8)
            
            (2,0,7) (2,2,11) (2,4,11) (2,6,9)
            
            (4,0,8) (4,2,10) (4,4,9) (4,6,8)
            
            (6,0,5) (6,2,9) (6,4,7) (6,6,4)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with transparent colorbar]